# Microservices seggregation

Tags: microservices

I am a little bit confused. In my company we have lots of different integrations, at the moment we have them within the same application. If we decide to go to micro service architecture, should every integration be separate service or they should all be in one?

Situation with integrations is that they are payment integrations, we communicate go payment providers and async responses from them, so we have to open couple of urls for each integration to receive answers from payment gateways. So they are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

While you could, I'd be very careful on over-engineering your solution.  Using docker containers, as an example, to create microservices still has overhead for each container running.  I would recommend starting out with just a handful of microservices.  Ideal candidates are if you need to N-Scale one microservice, versus another.

For example:
Service-A has a high load so it needs to scale to 4 instances
Service-B has a low load so just needs to 2 instances

Another great candidate is if you have a microservice that can be used across multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Should each integration will be different service that depends upon what type of integration. But yes micro service in general means build multiple small services that are completely independent.

One of the big issue with monolithic service is that its a single point of failure. So to medicate this risk you break your service in multiple small service. So that your integration layer do not fail if couple of service went down.

In the example you describe for payment, you can use hierarchy of micro service. You can dedicate one or two services to connect your external getaway and allow other service to connect thous one or two internal services.

One thing I highly recommend if you go for micro service think about implementing CI/CD (jenkins/chef), docker and kubernetes. If you do not have any automate you will soon find yourself doing lot more maintains of the services rather than developing.

In the end biggest reason you want micro service is make sure your integration layer always available and highly salable. Without some automation like, docker and kubernetes, you need lot of manual work to maintain the state of your service.